# How to change the font size of content when radio button clicks?

Tags: dialog

I have a WebView and I am loading the data from the backend.The data is very long paragraph and it is in Html format.It is working.I have to implement change font size settings to my application.When radio button named "small" clicks,text should appear in small font,when "large" clicks text should appear in large font.The content dispaly is done in ChapterDetailFragment.class.The dialg which shows the "change font option" is in Menu in actionbar and in drawer.

```
  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.font_change) {
        dialog = new Dialog(HomeActivity.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.font_change_dialog);
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

 //here i have to write the code for clicks of radiobutton "small","large"
    }
```

}

This is the line for loading paragraph to the array adapter

ParagraphAdapter.class

```
mViewHolder.mChapterContextTextView.loadData(getItem(position - 1).getContent(), "text/html; charset=UTF-8;", null);
```

I don't know how to implement this.Please anyone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in onClick of "large" radio button, save value LARGE for large.Similarly in onClick of small radio button(value SMALL for small )

public void onTextLarge(View view) {

```
    if (fragment.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("HomeFragment")){
        setSharedPreference("FONT","LARGE");
        fragment = new HomeFragment();
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

In the adapter,

```
 if (fontsize.equals("LARGE")) {
            mViewHolder.settings = mViewHolder.mChapterContextTextView.getSettings();
            mViewHolder.settings.setTextZoom(mViewHolder.settings.getTextZoom() + 30);
            mViewHolder.mChapterContextTextView.loadData(getItem(position - 1).getContent(),
                    "text/html; charset=UTF-8;", null);
```

Similarly done for fontsize.equals("SMALL"). :)